# Why is the path to a COM DLL needed in the PATH Environment variable when InProcServer32 key defines the full path to the DLL?

Tags: c++, com

I'm working on a legacy C++ component that's used within a C# web service. The C# Project reference displayed as valid, but at runtime, when the COM object is created a "CLSID lookup failed" exception was thrown. It turns out, the root path to where the DLL is located was needed for the CLSID resolution to work.

Why is the path to the DLL required to be present in the PATH Environment variable for the CLSID lookup to work?

Comment: Maybe the COM object isn't registered properly.  The path would not affect CLSID lookup, perhaps your C# project is giving an error message that does not correspond to the actual error

Comment: @M.M. Could be registration-free COM. I never used that newfangled stuff but I think it has to rely on the DLL being found via path lookup, if it isn't in the executable's directory.

Comment: I checked, and the DLL is registered correctly. After I added the path to the folder where the DLL resides, I ran Procmon.exe and saw the registry lookups on the CLSID succeed. I then removed the DLL path from the PATH environment variable and saw those same CLSID lookups fail. 'Depends.exe' shows the DLL in question has dependencies on other DLL's in the same folder and I'm guessing that's the reason the path has to be in the PATH environment variable. Id' rather be sure than just assume it, though.

Comment: @cg0x1 you could write an answer and self-accept

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. The C# Web Service is hosted in IIS and when the incoming call is dispatched, IIS probes for the DLL in the "\bin" folder of the Web Service. Since the COM component is a Project Reference, the physical file on disk is a Runtime Callable Wrapper, not the actual DLL. Adding the path to the DLL to the PATH environment variable gives IIS the ability to find the COM DLL and resolve it successfully.